# NSMutableAttributedString strange behaviour when setting NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, uicolor

I am trying to set the colour of text in an `NSMutableAttributedString`. I have a base class called `SectionTitleLabel`:

```
@implementation SectionTitleLabel

+ (void)initialize
{
    [[self appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontBold size:16.0f]];
}

@end
```

I have created a custom class which inherits from the above base class and have a method called addAttributes.

```
@interface PLSLabel : SectionTitleLabel

- (void)addAttributes:(NSArray *)words;
```

And in the implementation I have the following code:

```
- (void) addAttributes:(NSArray *)words
{
    self.words = words;

    [self setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];  // When this line is taken out the attributed text is not applied.

    for (NSString *word in self.words) {
         NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
        NSRange range = [self.text rangeOfString:link];
        NSLog(@"TEST TEST: %@", link);

        [attributedText addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]} range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];
        self.attributedText = attributedText;
    }
}
```

If I take out the following line from the addAttributes method 
`[self setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` then it doesn't work. As in the text remains completely white.

However when I have that line in the code then it works as expected (i.e: The words passed into the method become blue). I am hoping that someone can explain why this might be the case. And if it's a bug then it's good for other people to know a work around.

Many thanks.